# Suggestions for dealing with `exports` in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, require

**Theory:**

One of the things that appeals to me about node.js is using it as a command line tool.

In theory, I can write libraries in Javascript and place them in my `~/.node_libraries` directory, and then then I can reuse those libraries.

So for instance, I have a text.js in `~/.node_libraries`, and it has a bunch of text-related functions I use over and over (`depunctuate()`, `tokenize_text()`, things like that).

The beauty of this is that I could use the same `text.js` file with my command-line scripts and server side. Right now I'm doing all that text processing stuff with Python, but I'd like to just stick to one language.

**Practice:**

AFAICT, in order to create a node.js module, I have to attach everything that I want to be available to `exports` or `this`. I.e., in `text.js`, I have to do:

```
exports.depunctuate = depunctuate
```

or

```
this.depunctuate = depunctuate
```

If I use `exports`, I have problems with using the library server-side à la:

```
<script src=text.js></script>
```

because then I get **exports is not defined** errors.

If I use `this`, I avoid the error, but everything I export ends up getting attached to the window object.

Is there some way I can set up these libraries that avoid both of these problems? For instance, is there some way I can wrap the exporting of `exports` so that the var will be apparent to node, but not when it's used in a plain Javascript file on a server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about testing for the existence of the `exports` object before sticking stuff in it?

This has worked well for me so far, but maybe there are better ideas out there:

```
if(typeof(exports) !== 'undefined' && exports !== null) {
  exports.foo = foo;
  exports.bar = bar;
}
```

In CoffeeScript, this can be done a little more tersely:

```
[exports.foo, exports.bar] = [foo, bar] if exports?
```

Comment: That did it! Gotta love Stackoverflow... BTW, why can't I just say `if(exports)`?

Comment: Wait, on second thought, I am still able to get to `window.depunctuate`.

Answer (score 7):

so this comes into a namespacing issue. Unless a function is called with the new operator you will get a this context === to window (global). A way to dodge this is:

```
(function( exports ) {
  /* put your depuncuate definition here to keep it from leaking to the global */
  exports.depunctuate = depunctuate;
})( (typeof exports === 'undefined') ? myAppNamespace : exports );
```